# How to show the function of integrable on a set minus a set with measure 0

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $A$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R^k}$; let $B$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$; let $Q=A\times B$. Let $f: Q\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Show that if $\int_Q f$ exists, then

$$\int_{y\in B}f(x,y)$$ exists for $x\in A-D$, where $D$ is a set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R^k}$.

My work

Let $Q’=((A-D)\times B)=(A\times B)-(D\times B)$. Then, I only need to show $D\times B$ has measure $0$ in $Q$.

Since it has measure $0$ is it integrable on $Q’$, thus by Fubini theorem it is $\int_{y\in B}f(x,y)$ exists $\forall x\in A-D$

Is this a correct way to thinking? And how can I say $D\times B$ has measure $0$ in Q?

Comment: While it's good that you've posted an attempt, it is easily seen to be incomplete. There is nowhere in your proof where you made use of the hypothesis "$\int_Q f$ exists"; i.e that $f$ is (I assume you mean Riemann) integrable on $Q$. Also, what is $D$ in your proof? Notice that the question introduces $D$ in the form of an existential quantifier. So you need to show there exists a $D$ such that "blablabla". Summary: you need to use your hypothesis "$\int_Q f$ exists" somehow to show the existence of a set $D$ such that "blablabla".

Comment: For your last part however, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then, since $D \subset A$ has measure 0, there is a countable cover of $D$ by open rectangles $U_1, \dots, U_s,\dots$ such that $\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}v(U_s) < \epsilon.$ Then, $U_1 \times B, \dots U_s \times B, \dots$ is a countable collection of rectangles which covers $D \times B$, and such that $\sum_{s=1}^{\infty} v(U_s \times B) < \epsilon \cdot v(B)$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $D \times B$ has measure zero as well.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I think I use if $\int_Q f$ exists ($Q=A\times B$)  then, $\int_{Q’} f$ exists ($Q’=(A-D)\times B$). D is a set with measure. I used the theorem if the function is integrable on $Q$, then it is failed to continuous on a subset of $Q$ with measure $0$. Is this makes my prove more clear?